# Build error in xcode 4.2 ARC enabled project when I linked with custom page controller

Tags: iphone

```
`d: duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_MenuDetail in /Users/pinakinsoni/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ShushiYoshi-alptwsfkyxzpufedcylyehqubxng/Build/Intermediates/ShushiYoshi.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Sushi Yoshi.build/Objects-normal/i386/MenuDetail.o`
```

and

```
/Users/pinakinsoni/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ShushiYoshi-alptwsfkyxzpufedcylyehqubxng/Build/Intermediates/ShushiYoshi.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Sushi Yoshi.build/Objects-normal/i386/Menu.o for architecture i386
    Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow... you should explain your question more and also proper formatting will help... this time I will do it for you... :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you've got a class called `MenuDetail` that's defined in two places: probably in `MenuDetail.m` and `Menu.m`. Are you doing this in `Menu.m`?

```
#import "MenuDetail.m"
```

you should import `MenuDetail.h` instead.